# Map function is not working when try to fetch data inside react-simple-tree-menu

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, treeview, react-bootstrap

I am trying to fetch children tag details from parent tags. When I use `{state.tagData.allTagDetails.map((e: any) => {}` , only I can access `e.propertyname` (only the data that parent tag has). I can not access children tag details. There is a issue in `e.childTags.map((item: any) => {}` map function. Could you please help me to fix this?

This is my code.

```
<div style={{ listStyleType: "none", display: "inline" }}>
          {state.tagData.allTagDetails.map((e: any) => {
            return (
              <TreeMenu
                cacheSearch
                data={[
                  {
                    key: e.id,
                    label: e.name,
                    child: e.childTags.map((item: any) => {
                      nodes:[
                        {
                          key: item.id,
                          label:item.name
                        }
                      ]
                     }),
                  },
                ]}
                debounceTime={125}
                disableKeyboard={false}
                hasSearch={false}
                onClickItem={onClickPlusButton}
                resetOpenNodesOnDataUpdate={false}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know properties of your children from the beginning, then you don't even need to iterate at all. Just set the object properties directly:

```
child: {
    nodes:[
        {
            key: e.id,
            label:e.name
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TreeMenu
                cacheSearch
                data={state.tagData.allTagDetails.map((e: any) => {
                  return {
                    key: e.id,
                    label:e.name,
                    color:e.color,
                    parentTag_id: null,
                    nodes:e.childTags ? e.childTags.map((item:any)=>{
                      return{
                        key: item.id,
                        label:item.name,
                        color:item.color,
                        parentTag_id:item.parentTag_id
                      }
                    }):(" "
                    )
                  };
                })}
                debounceTime={125}
                disableKeyboard={false}
                hasSearch={false}
                onClickItem={(e) => onClicktag(e)}
                resetOpenNodesOnDataUpdate={false}
              />
```